# Dask Memory Error with smaller than memory dataset

Tags: python, memory, dask, large-data, bigdata

I am trying to quickly calculate the correlation matrix of a large dataset (745 rows x 18,048 columns) in Python 3. The dataset was originally read from a 50MB netCDF file and after some manipulation it came to this size. All of the data is stored as float32s. Therefore, I calculated that the final correlation matrix should be around 1.2 GB, which should easily fit into my 8 GB RAM. Using pandas' DataFrame and its methods, it can calculate the entire correlation matrix in around 100 minutes so it is possible to calculate it.

I read up on the dask module and decided to implement it. However, when I try to calculate using the same method, it almost immediately runs into a MemoryError, even though it should fit into memory. After some fiddling I realized it even fails on a relatively small 1000 x 1000 dataset. Is there something else that's going on underneath that is causing this error? I have posted my code below:

```
import dask.dataframe as ddf
# prepare data in dataframe called df
daskdf = ddf.from_pandas(df, chunksize=1000)
correlation = daskdf.corr()
correlation.compute()
```

And here's the error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mughi/Documents/College Stuff/Project DIVA/Preprocessing Data/DaskCorr.py", line 36, in <module>
    correlation.compute()
  File "C:\Users\mughi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 94, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mughi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 201, in compute
    results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mughi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py", line 76, in get
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mughi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 500, in get_async
    raise(remote_exception(res, tb))
dask.async.MemoryError: 

Traceback
---------
  File "C:\Users\mughi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 266, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "C:\Users\mughi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 247, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "C:\Users\mughi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 3283, in cov_corr_chunk
    keep = np.bitwise_and(mask[:, None, :], mask[:, :, None])
```

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend that you just use NumPy

Comment: Pandas may make copies of your data without warning.

Comment: Is there any way to stop Pandas from doing so or do I have to stick with numpy's implementation of correlation?